Finding the period of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\sin\left(\frac{x^{\circ}}{n}\right)$
So one of the last questions on my city's local team math competition is confusing, and I need some help (don't worry, this is after the competition). The question seems simple and goes like this.

What is the period of this function? $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\sin\left(\frac{x^{\circ}}{n}\right)$$

I do not know where to start with this question because: $1.$ period is typically in radians and $2.$ nothing like this was in the practice sheets.
If anyone can help me that would be greatly appreciated!

What is the period of $~\sin(x^\circ/3),~$ given that the period of $~\sin(x^\circ) = 360^\circ ~?$  What is the least common multiple of $~{1,2,3,\cdots,10}~?$

It will be easier to study $f'(x)$ instead. Notice $f'(x)$ has a global maximum at $x = 0$ where all $\cos\frac{0^\circ}{n} = 1$. In order for $T$ to be a period of $f(x)$ and hence of $f'(x)$, one need $\cos\frac{T^\circ}{n} = 1$ for $n =1,\ldots,10$.

By definition we look for $T\circ$ (minimum) such that $\forall x$
$$f(x^\circ+T^\circ)=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\sin\left(\frac{x^\circ+T^\circ}{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\sin\left(\frac{x^\circ}{n}\right)=f(x)$$
then for any $n$ we need $\frac {T^\circ}{n}=k_n\cdot 360^\circ $ that is, as suggested in the comments
$$T^\circ =\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) \cdot 360^\circ =2520\cdot 360^\circ \tag 1$$

As noticed, the result given in $(1)$ is certainly a period but, in general, we can't be sure that this is the (minumum) period since for any proper divisor $d$ of $2520$ we can't exclude a priori that $d\cdot 360^\circ$ is also a period.
As suggested in the comments by achille hui, to check that $(1)$ is the period, since $f'(0^\circ)=(1+\ldots+1/10)$ is a global maximum, we also need that $\cos (T^\circ/n)=1$ for any $n=1,\ldots,10$.
Therefore we can finally conclude that $(1)$ is the period.

The LCM of the integers up to 10 is 2520.

Yes of course $= 2\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 2\cdot 3$.

This isn't a proof that you've found the period. All you've shown is that this number is some integer number of periods, but that integer may be greater than $1$.  It's entirely plausible that using the sum-of-sines formula, the sum can be simplified in a way that shows a shorter period.

@RobertShore Thanks, I thought that for example $2520/2=1260$ doesn't work because using that $\sin((x+T)/8)\neq \sin(x/8)$ while all others components are periodic. Please add an answer which complete the proof. Thanks

@RobertShore Do you think I need to add this explanation into the answer? Thanks

@user To make it complete, I think so.

But this is still not complete as you only ruled out the cases where only one summand is not periodic; it is quite likely a priori that for $T=2520°/k$ for some $k>11$ is not a period for at least two terms, but makes the whole sum periodic

@JianingSong Thanks! I try to revise it in a final form.

@JianingSong I've added a solution based on the chacking for all the proper divisors.

The period is not necessarily a multiple of $360°$. I admit that this is not at all a trivial question.

@JianingSong So there is not a way to solve it? :(

Not necessarily, considering the maximum as what you have done is a very interesting method! :)

Yes! full credits to @achillehui of course!

But if I got it correctly, there is a calculation error: we have $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{10}\sin\dfrac{\pi x}{180n}$, so $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{10}\dfrac{\pi}{180n}\cos\dfrac{\pi x}{180n} = \sum_{n=1}^{10}\dfrac{\pi}{180n}\cos\dfrac{x°}{n}$, which means that $f'(0) = \dfrac{\pi}{180}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{10}\right)$.

Yes of course! I fix that! Thanks

I don't know how they thought a group of high schoolers would know how to do this. there was a 4-way tie for 18/20 bc everyone got this wrong. ;-;

Thank you everyone!!!

@Sebas31415 Yes indeed this is not trivial at all, if they were not asking for a period! You are welcome, bye.

In general, there is no reason to suppose that the smallest period of the sum of two periodic functions is the LCM of the smallest period of each sum. Sadly, there are already many questions on this site assuming that it is, for example this one, this one and this one. So I think that a complete answer is necessary.
Claim. Let $\omega_1,\omega_2,\cdots,\omega_n>0$ be distinct, then a period of
$$
f(x):=A_1\sin(\omega_1x+\varphi_1)+A_2\sin(\omega_2x+\varphi_2)+\cdots+A_n\sin(\omega_nx+\varphi_n)
$$
is a period of each summand $A_i\sin(\omega_ix+\varphi_i)$.
Proof. If $T$ is a period of $f(x)$, then $T$ is also a period of its $(2j)-$th derivative
$$
f^{(2j)}(x)=(-1)^j(\omega_1^{2j}A_1\sin(\omega_1x+\varphi_1)+\omega_2^{2j}A_2\sin(\omega_2x+\varphi_2)+\cdots+\omega_n^{2j}A_n\sin(\omega_nx+\varphi_n)).
$$
Since the Vandermonde matrix $(\omega_i^{2j})_{1\le i\le n,0\le j\le n-1}$ is invertible, each $A_i\sin(\omega_ix+\varphi_i)$ is a linear conbination of $f(x),f''(x),\cdots,f^{(2n-2)}(x)$, so $T$ is a period of each $A_i\sin(\omega_ix+\varphi_i)$.
With the property above, we can now safely say that the period of the function in the original question is indeed
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(360\times 1,360\times 2,\cdots,360\times 10)=360\times 2520.
$$
